# Bethe approximation for two-dimensional Ising model

Tags: thermodynamics

The logarithm of the canonical partition function in two dimensions when the interaction energy is zero and in the absence of the external magnetic field is expected to be log 2 in the thermodynamic limit. It is not clear whether this limiting value has been indicated in any text or research paper, when Bethe approximation is described?Are there any books or reviews where the partition functions have been tabulated, even in the absence of the magnetic field, for various values of the interaction energy (J) while employing Bethe approximation?